# PHP Juggling Mayhem

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a page that warns people when they leave my website, I can't seem to get the punctuation correct. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$link = (string) $_GET['link'];

echo 'Are you sure you want to leave this site?<br />';
echo 'Destination: <strong>'.$link.'</strong><br />';

echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="15" width="100%">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href='".$link."'">';
echo '<font color="white" size="5">Movies</font>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

This code has proven to work for a regular link like this

```
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Proceed</a>';
```

For reference, my error message says this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in X:\path\to\file\index.php on line 9
```

Also, if you need to know, I use a link like this that directs my exit page:

```
<a href="/link/to/exit/page/?link=http://www.example.com">
```

I can't however seem to get the punctuation correct for it to work in my table. Does anyone know how I can format that so it will work in my table?

Comment: This is why string formatting with `heredoc` is great. Or `sprintf()` with shorter strings. Worth reading up on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: I'm with @Darragh - when I get stuff that's this messy, I often find a bit of printf to be helpful: `printf('<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href=\'%s\';">', $link);`

Comment: or MVC. Heredoc is hideous

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
echo '<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href='".$link."'">';
```

should be

```
echo '<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href=\''.$link.'\'">';
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Care to be more constructive?

Comment: Look at rendered HTML. Or just rip off my answer. Either one.

Comment: seriously niet. you should point out why and not just be snide about it. I know it is because the single quotes but we all should be advising on using listeners and not inline js. Plus nobody said anything about this being a pretty stupid idea to begin with.

Comment: not sure I would have marked this as the correct answer cause niet's is more informative, but I also wouldn't leave it at negative one either

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the colour coding, it's not quite right.

```
echo '<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href=\''.$link.'\';">';
```

That should do it - notice the colour coding here?

As an aside, don't allow arbitrary input to be dumped. I could do:

`/link/to/exit/page?link=<script type="text/javascript">alert('lol I just haxed you');</script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href='".$link."'">';
```

should be

```
echo '<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href='.$link.'">';
```

There is no need for another set of quotes.

Comment: long past too late, sir. plus you should see the results of this exact answer in the answers already. Niet will downvote you

Comment: also, there is a need for another set of quotes. single quotes.